# FlareGet - Bad quality package

Tags: package-management, deb, lintian, flareget

I'm aware that `bad quality` doesn't mean the `.deb` is not good,
but I don't know the publisher and don't know if I should trust them.

I'm asking here those who installed FlareGet and can give their opinion about it.
Here are the error details:

```
Lintian check results for /home/user/Downloads/flareget_4.3-95_amd64.deb:
E: flareget: dir-or-file-in-etc-opt etc/opt/chrome/
E: flareget: dir-or-file-in-etc-opt etc/opt/chrome/native-messaging-hosts/
E: flareget: dir-or-file-in-etc-opt etc/opt/chrome/native-messaging-hosts/com.flareget.flareget.json
N: Some overrides were ignored, since the tags were marked "non-overridable".
N: Use --verbose for more information.
```

*edit: I'm running Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely ignore this error.

This is caused because Ubuntu does not recommend adding any file in `/etc` folder, but that is required for Google Chrome browser integration.